# Vue - style user input in confirm message (allow specific html tags)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, xss

Using Vue, I want to show a confirmation modal that says something like "Are you sure you want to delete '{{itemName}}'?".

That's easy enough with a Javascript string being bound to a variable which is embedded in the template.

However, if I want to put the `itemName` in italics to emphasis it, the only way I can find is to use `v-html`, which of course would open it up to XSS.

Is there any way to style part of the string?

Comment: why not just do `<i>{{itemName}}</i>` in the modal?

Comment: No. But are you sure that there's an XSS vulnerability? If `itemName` is not supplied in any way by the user, there's no XSS.

Comment: Is it helpful to use v-text instead of v-html? <i v-text="itemName"> </i>https://012.vuejs.org/api/directives.html#v-text

Comment: `itemName` comes from the end user, so yes, it could be used for XSS. Also I can't just use `<i>{{itemName}}</i>` in the modal, since the content of the modal is not specific to it modal itself - its just a slot. I would like to be able to define the whole string like I suggested above (or other things as well - "Are you sure you want to exit without saving changes" for example).

Comment: @AllanJardine Can you put a <span> element around the variable?

Comment: @AllanJardine Do you think it will work? https://jsfiddle.net/varit05/hyd9L6r4/

Comment: @varit05 - The problem there is that the question string is static. Also it is effectively defining the language. What if I wanted two variables to be shown in the output?

Comment: Well, then you can use computed property. Like I did here: https://jsfiddle.net/varit05/hyd9L6r4/

Comment: Could you give me an example of this two scenario in jsfiddle with `v-html`? `The problem there is that the question string is static. Also it is effectively defining the language. `

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to use a package like [sanitize-html](https://github.com/punkave/sanitize-html). Here is how I would do it:

**Install:**

```
npm install sanitize-html
```

**main.js:**

```
import sanitizeHTML from 'sanitize-html';
Vue.prototype.$sanitize = sanitizeHTML;
```

**YourComponent.vue:**

```
<div v-html="$sanitize(itemName)" />
```

Have a look at the [README](https://github.com/punkave/sanitize-html#readme) for more information about default options for allowed tags and attributes.

**EDIT resp. Alternatives:**

`sanitize-html` has a drawback of a 327 KB weight. But there are smaller packages available:

- [DOMPurify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify) (15 KB)
- [js-xss](https://github.com/leizongmin/js-xss) (28 KB)

---

**EDIT 2:**

There is a package [vue-dompuritfy-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-dompurify-html) which we are using in our projects now. After installing you can simply use

```html
<div v-dompurify-html="itemName" />
```

Bonus: with the use of this package you cover the recommended eslint rule [vue/no-v-html](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/no-v-html.html)

Comment: Thanks for this - it looks like it might be the only way. But sanitize-html is 329K minified!

Comment: Hi @AllanJardine, in Angular 1.x there is a service [angular-sanitize](https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-sanitize), which I used in the past on my angular projects. It fits most of my needs and it weights minified only 7 KB. May it's possible to adapt this to Vue?

Comment: Hi @AllanJardine, after some investigation I've updated my answer with some smaller alternatives.

Answer (score 3):

Define your modal as such:

*template*

```html
<div class="modal">
  <slot></slot>
  <button @click="$emit(true)">Yes</button>
  <button @click="$emit(false)">No</button>
</div>
```

*styling*

```css
.modal > em {
  /* apply anything you want here */
}
```

Then  use your modal in a companant:

*template*

```html
<template>
  ...
    <modal>Are you sure you want to delete <em>{{itemName}}</em>?</modal>
  ...
</template>
```

Comment: I guess that's probably the most "Vue" way of doing it, but it seems a little over the top of need to create another component for every message I want to show in a modal.

Comment: Are you referring to <em>?

Comment: OK you are probably referring to the modal component itself. Creating a separate component for modals provides you a single place for modifying modals wherever they appear in your app. This is part of the principle of separation of concerns.

Comment: Also, this code expresses the intent behind it very clearly in that: modals are components of your application, they display a message that is provided by their context, the messages can have semantics provided by html (like emphasis) which the modal chooses how to display through custom CSS, and finally that the modal replies back to the context the result of the user's interaction with it.

Comment: I see the point there, but I don't really see the need to have multiple separate components for things like "Are you sure you want to delete this {item}?" / "Are you sure you want to complete this {action}?" / "Leaving this {page} will undo changes" / etc. I've got my modal / alert display. I just want a message inside it which is easily defined. Its the HTML in the text that is the issue - it might contain user input data, so its not safe.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen other answers, I recommend Rashad Saleh's answer, a model with slot, you can show your model with `v-if` and switch content with `v-*` directives, then you don't need to create each template for each case

I post another answer, it goes totally a different way, `sweet-alert` it won't conflict with your vue and use in totally javascript way.

```js
var something = document.getElementById('xss').value

var toshow = encodeURIComponent(something)

Swal.fire({
  title: 'Are you sure?',
  html: "You won't be able to revert <b><em>" + toshow + "</em></b>!",
  type: 'warning',
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
  cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
  confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
}).then((result) => {
  if (result.value) {
    Swal.fire(
      'Deleted!',
      'Your file has been deleted.',
      'success'
    )
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.33.1/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>

<input id="xss" value="<script>alert('xss')</script>">
```

you may need to customize the style for sweet alert although it's pretty enough, for more info refer https://sweetalert2.github.io/