# v-html not rendering dynamic HTML data inside div

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a standalone vue.js app , its converted from angular 1 + bootstrap to vue+bootstrap.
In angular i used sanitizer to render ajax html data inside component , in vue what is the simple alternative to that ?

HTML>

```
   <div class="detailsText" v-if="object.definition != ''" data-html="true" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" v-bind:title="strip(object.definition)" v-html="object.definition"></div>
```

Javascript >

```
var vueobject = new Vue({
el: '#compactViewController',
data: {
    OBJECTS: [],
    CURRENT_PAGE: 1,
    PERMISSION_KEYS: parent.OPTION_PERMISSIONS,
    filterText: "",
    pageSize: pageSize
}
...
```

HTML Tags `<div>`,`<b>` not rendered
   [image]

```js
new Vue({
 el: "#app",
  data: {
   channel: "<b>hello world!</b>"
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.0/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="channels">
    TEST: <span v-html="channel"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

It works fine when we use v-html with local html value , same will not work with raw html coming from API call.

Comment: Can you create a quick fiddle for that? Or please post more code?

Comment: @YomS. I have edited my question , the requirement is to render a raw html coming from API using v-html , there is a solution but its node based (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55262267/does-vue-by-default-provide-security-for-or-protects-against-xss)

Comment: It doesn't matter where the raw content comes from, as long as it's valid HTML, it should really work right off the bat with `v-html`. Something's missing here.

Comment: Please make sure the raw HTML is valid, as in not missing closing tag, typos, etc.

Comment: @YomS. Thanks Bro , the html was coming in escaped format &gt,&lt , It working now ..