# @click doesn't work when rendering it using v-html

Tags: javascript, vue.js

#### I have a  component which I wish I could create rows and columns with data and columns object from the parent.

There is a situation where I need to render an html template to create a clickable link, I make it want to display the link in the `Actions` column. **vue version: ^2.5.17**

below is the code from **parent.vue**:

```
// parent.vue
<table-component :data="category" :column="column" class="bg-red-200 py-4 mt-8"/>
```

```
// parent.vue
data(){
  return {
    modalMode: '',
    isShowModalEdit: false,
    category: [
      { id: 1, name: 'Jasa Pre-Order', color: '#eb4034' },
      { id: 2, name: 'Jualan', color: '#fcba03' },
      { id: 3, name: 'Jasa Design', color: '#9f34eb' },
    ],
  }
}
```

```
// parent.vue
methods: {
  toggleModalEdit(){
    this.isShowModalEdit = !this.isShowModalEdit
    this.modalMode = 'EDIT'
  }
}
```

```
// parent.vue
computed: {
            column() {
                return [
                    {
                        dataField: 'name',
                        text: 'Name',
                    },
                    {
                        dataField: 'color',
                        text: 'Category Color',
                        formatter: (cell,row) => {
                            return `
                                <div style="background-color: ${cell};" class="rounded-full h-8 w-8 flex items-center justify-center mr-2"></div>
                                <div class="font-bold text-gray-500">${cell}</div>
                            `
                        },
                        classes: (cell, row, rowIndex, colIndex) => {
                            return 'flex';
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        dataField: 'actions',
                        text: 'Actions',
                        formatter: (cell,row) => {
                            return `
                                <a href="#" @click="${this.toggleModalEdit}" class="text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-900">Edit</a>
                            `
                        },
                    },
                ]
            },
}
```

and this is the sample code from **component.vue**:

```
// component.vue
<tbody class="bg-white divide-y divide-gray-200">
  <tr v-for="(row, rowIndex) in data" :key="rowIndex">
    <td v-for="(col, colIndex) in column" :key="col.dataField" :class=" col.classes ? col.classes(row[col.dataField],row,rowIndex,colIndex) : '' " v-html=" col.formatter ? col.formatter(row[col.dataField],row) : row[col.dataField] " class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500"></td>
  <tr>
</tbody>
```

```
// component.vue
props: {
            data: {
                type: Array,
                required: true
            },
            column: {
                type: Array,
                required: true
            },
}
```

the result is like this:

[image]

but the link in the `Actions` column does not work as it should, I hope that when clicking this link will run the method of the perent namely `toggleModalEdit`. and this is what the link looks like when i inspect it:

[image]

i am still new to vue, i am not sure what i did best or not, i hope you guys can help.

Comment: Use the `template` and `slot` if you are okay to use with markups. or else use the `new Vue` to create the vue instances dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is, that the HTML inside the v-html directive is [not processed by Vue's template compiler](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-html) at all.

Because the compiler doesn't compile this HTML, the `@click` is not interpreted (but simply rendered without triggering any action).

For this to work, you'd need to iterate over all columns and initialize a new component that handles what's inside the cell yourself directly in HTML (and not in some string that's gonna be rendered later on).

I guess that this is enough - if you still need to interpret what's in the string, you may [use `Vue.compile` to interpret the content](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-compile). But be careful as it's **not safe** in case there's some malicious code in it - but since the directive by default [has no sanitizing at all](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/6333), I guess that's just the way Vue.js works.

Comment: "for security reasons" I don't think so. It just doesn't make any sense conceptually. From a security standpoint, I can still perform arbitrary XSS, whether the code is first compiled by Vue's compiler or not.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I clarified that in my post. Nevertheless, the use of `Vue.compile` is still regarding security, because attackers get more options using that.

Comment: Remember that I can still inject `<script>Vue.compile(/* ... whatever ... */)</script>` so this doesn't really matter. It's a conceptual concern.

Comment: Wow, being used to Angular it's scary that Vue actually [doesn't do any sanitizing by default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55263280/12507396), didn't know that.
Then you're probably right about the background.
I don't agree in your statement that it doesn't make sense to have something like that, because the question has some use case for it, but that's not the key point of the discussion.

Comment: Thanks to @idmean for the answers

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **@SimplyComple0x78** for the answer, I marked your suggestions:

> For this to work, you'd need to iterate over all columns and initialize a new component that handles what's inside the cell yourself directly in HTML (and not in some string that's gonna be rendered later on).

so I try to create and initialize a new component, I call it `element-generator`. [reference from here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html). here's the code:

```
// element-generator.vue
<script>
    export default {
        render: function (createElement) {
            const generatedChildren = (child) => {
                if(!child) return // when child of undefined
                if(typeof child === 'string') return child // when children is String
                return child.map((e,i,a)=>{
                    if(typeof child[i] == 'string'){
                        return child[i]
                    }else{
                        return createElement(
                            child[i].tag,
                            child[i].attributes,
                            generatedChildren(child[i].children) // javascript recursive
                        )
                    }
                })
            }
            return createElement(
                this.formatter.html.tag,
                this.formatter.html.attributes,
                generatedChildren(this.formatter.html.children)
            )
        },
        props: {
            formatter: {
                type: Object,
                required: true
            },
        },
    }
</script>
```

and I no longer use `v-html` in `component.vue` instead I just do a check inside `<td>` and call `element-generator` to handle what's inside the cell:

```
// component.vue
<tbody class="bg-white divide-y divide-gray-200">
    <tr v-for="(row, rowIndex) in data" :key="rowIndex">
        <td v-for="(col, colIndex) in column" :key="col.dataField"
            :class=" col.classes ? col.classes(row[col.dataField],row,rowIndex,colIndex) : '' "
            class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500"
        >
            <element-generator v-if="col.formatter" :formatter="col.formatter(row[col.dataField],row)"></element-generator>
            <div v-else>{{row[col.dataField]}}</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

and in `parent.vue` I replaced the String with the Object that will be passed to the `element-generator` later, it looks like this:

```
// parent.vue
computed: {
    column() {
        return [
            {
                dataField: 'name',
                text: 'Name',
            },
            {
                dataField: 'color',
                text: 'Category Color',
                formatter: (cell,row) => {
                    return {
                        html: {
                            tag: 'div',
                            attributes: {
                                class: 'flex'
                            },
                            children:[
                                {
                                    tag: 'div',
                                    attributes: {
                                        style: `background-color: ${cell};`,
                                        class: 'rounded-full h-8 w-8 flex items-center justify-center mr-2',
                                    },
                                },
                                {
                                    tag: 'div',
                                    attributes: {
                                        class: 'font-bold text-gray-500',
                                    },
                                    children: cell
                                },
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
            },
            {
                dataField: 'actions',
                text: 'Actions',
                formatter: (cell,row) => {
                    return {
                        html: {
                            tag: 'a',
                            attributes: {
                                class: 'text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-900',
                                on: {
                                    click: this.toggleModalEdit
                                },
                                attrs: {
                                    href: "#"
                                },
                            },
                            children: 'Edit'
                        },
                    }
                },
            },
        ]
    },
},
```

then when I inspect it in the browser, the result is like this(this is different from the previous one):
[image]

and finally what I want to display when **Edit** is clicked is now displayed:
[image]

Thank you very much everyone.